# Split string into individual numbers in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, split, sum

The following code searches the table `#operations` for every `<td>` with the dynamic class `".fuel "+ACID`:

```
let k = 0;  
let ac_fuel = 0;
parsed.data.forEach(arrayWithinData => {
    let ACID = parsed.data[k][0];
    if($("#operations td").hasClass("fuel "+ACID)) {
        console.log("we have a "+ACID);
        console.log(($("#operations td.fuel."+ACID).text()));
        ac_fuel += parseFloat($("#operations td.fuel."+ACID).html());
        console.log(ac_fuel);
    }
    k++;
})
```

ac_fuel is logged as a string of numbers e.g.:

```
61.001.001.00643.00632.006.001.002181.22
```

How would I split these numbers up so I can add them together? the desired result is the sum of every `<td>` element with the class `".fuel "+ACID`:

```
61.00 + 1.00 + 643.00 + 632.00 + 6.00 + 1.00 + 2181.22
```

Comment: Can you post the HTML that produces this?

Comment: While parsing instead of appending push them in an array and add them later.

Comment: Not sure how is this possible, as you are already using `ac_fuel += parseFloat(..)`. Can you create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/1823841) here to show the issue happening.

Comment: @CertainPerformance https://jsfiddle.net/q81wv65o/

Answer (score -1):

You should use js .split function

```
let numsString = '61.001.001.00643.00632.006.001.002181.22';
let numsArr = numsString.split('.');
let summ = 0;

// set + before num, so it will be converted from string to num
numsArr.map(num => summ += +num);

console.log(summ);
```

So in your code I believe this will be something like this

```
let k = 0;  
let ac_fuel = 0;
parsed.data.forEach(arrayWithinData => {
  let ACID = parsed.data[k][0];
  if($("#operations td").hasClass("fuel "+ACID)) {
    ac_fuel += parseFloat($("#operations td.fuel."+ACID).html());
  }
  k++;
})

let numsString = $("#operations td.fuel." + ACID).html();
let numsArr = numsString.split('.');
let summ = 0;

// set + before num, so it will be converted from string to num
numsArr.map(num => summ += +num);

ac_fuel += summ;
console.log(ac_fuel);
```